# Autocomplete dropdown item text color in Theme.Holo.Light issue

Tags: android, android-theme

i searched an entire day for this problem, no workaround worked and I would like some fresh pair of eyes to take a look at this. I am using Android 3.2 and theme Holo.Light with ActionBar(important).

My layout xml:

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocompleteSearchTxt"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.52"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

In Android Manifest file: `android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.Workaround"`

In themes.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light.Workaround" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewLight</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.DropDownItemLight</item>
</style>
```

In styles.xml file:

```
  <style name="AutoCompleteTextViewLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.DropDownItemLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

Now here I tried with my own colors, red, blue...colors that would stand out.

The result is ... nothing. It changes nothing, when i write chars in the autocomplete, i can see it is completing as i go but the dropdown item text color is not seen at all. It's transparent, or white on white(on real device).

I am not able to understand what i am doing wrong. Did someone resolved this problem before? Please any clues would be great. 
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the text color of dropdown in an AutoCompleteTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876840/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-dropdown-in-an-autocompletetextview)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bit late but in case you still need an answer...

How are you setting your array adapter? If you are using:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,my_list_of_values);
```

then, the default layout provided by Android would override anything you do in your xml.

Instead, why don't you try to create a layout file with a textview component and then use that when instantiating your `ArrayAdapter`?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.your_textview_layout,my_list_of_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                          (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourList){                     
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    ((TextView) v).setTextSize(14);                             
     Typeface Type = getFont () ;  // custom method to get a font from "assets" folder
     ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Type);              
    ((TextView) v).setTextColor(YourColor);                                             
     ((TextView) v) .setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        return v;
     }          
     };

    YourAutoCompleteView.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
```