# AutoCompleteText dropdown text color

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I am using an `AutoCompleteTextView` but am running into the problem of white text on a white background in the dropdown menu.

If I start typing in the field the dropdown appears and if I click in the dropdown it chooses the correct item and places it in the text field. I just cannot see what it is I am clicking.

```
        ctAutoText = new AutoCompleteTextView( this );
        ctAutoText.setHint( "CT Ratio" );
        ctAutoText.setLayoutParams( editLP );
        ctAutoText.setId( 1001 );

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cTRatioList.toArray( new String[cTRatioList.size()] ) );
        ctAutoText.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the text color of dropdown in an AutoCompleteTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876840/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-dropdown-in-an-autocompletetextview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my `ArrayAdapter`. Use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
             cTRatioList.toArray( new String[cTRatioList.size()] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text colour inside dropdow list, please follow:https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787982/1265456